# Particles js not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, particles.js

I have this demo site made by Wordpress having the [particles.js](https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/) script based slide in hero section. But the particles won't appear until I resize the window. After resizing the window particles appears correctly... Any way to fix this??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Works for me on mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your particles are loading only via `resize`, because in your custom JS you trigger the `resize` manually, but there are JavaScript errors.

```
$(window).load(function(){window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));$(window).resize()})
```

The jQuery `$` alias hasn't been defined for your `custom.js` file to use, so replace that code with this:

```
jQuery(window).load(function($){window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));$(window).resize()})
```

same with your `index.php` file, the following JS has the same issue:

```
$(window).trigger('resize');
$(window).resize(); };
```

You could probably just remove those two lines since you have your `custom.js` file loaded, once you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks there are some errors in the console

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
>       at custom.js:1 (index):406 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument.onLoad ((index):406)